# Javascript function only works within a function (with c interface)

Tags: javascript, c++, html

I am really new to javascript and I am writing an API for getting the server status from the c++ code that's running underneath. I understand this question may (or may not) be project dependent, but I'm just wondering if anyone has a insight of what could possibly be wrong here.

So I want to call the "checkServerStatusCpp()" function, which is implemented in c++ on  "Manager.cpp". (I am reusing someone else code and all I need to do is to compile and the interface will be automatically generated. I will attach as much info as possible.)

I found that if wrap my call within a function, the native c++ code would be executed.

```
a = function(){ manager.getServerStatusCpp(); };
a();  // no problem calling the function in Manager.cpp
```

otherwise it won't work

```
manager.getServerStatusCpp();  
// function getServerStatusCpp() in Manager.cpp is never called.
```

Here are my related files.

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <!-- all other js/css files are in here. -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/system.media.manager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/man.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <fieldset> <legend> <b> server status </b> </legend>
      <div class="pad10">    
        <p> <a onclick="refresh()" id="refresh" href="#"> Refresh </a></p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>


    <script>
    var manager = new System.Manager("1");

    function refresh() {
        // this works - the native function will be called.
        a = function(){manager.getServerStatusCpp();};
        a();

        // if i put this the function in C++ will not be executed.
        manager.getServerStatusCpp();
    }
    function onGetServerStatus(myObject) {
        //do something
    };

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**man.js**  (I am rewriting the auto-generated function where)

```
System.Manager = System.Media.IManager.extend({

    init : function(instance) {
        this._super(instance);
        this.count = 0;
    },

    getServerStatusCppCallback: function( myObject ) {
        console.log("getServerStatusCpp-->"  + JSON.stringify(myObject));
        onGetServerStatus(myObject);
    },   

});
```

**system.media.manager.js** (This file is automatically generated)

```
System.Media = System.Media || {};
System.Media.IManager = System.Interface.extend({

    init : function(instance) {
        this._super("System::IManager", instance);
    },

    getServerStatuCppsCallback: function(  myObject ) {
        console.log("getServerStatusCpp-->"  + JSON.stringify(myObject));
    },
    getServerStatusCpp: function() {
        this.call(
        {"method": "IManager::getServerStatusCpp", "params":{ } }, this.getServerStatusCppCallback, []);
    },

});
    /**
     * End of IManager interface
    */

});
```

Note: Manager.cpp, Manager.h are the native c++ code, and IManager.h implement the js interface.

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: `this` is probably wrong.

Comment: Do you have both `System.manager` and `System.Manager`, or is that a typo?

Comment: true, that was a typo. have already corrected.